# CefSharp WPF turn off transparent background

Tags: wpf, cefsharp

I am using cefsharp version 79.1.360 for WPF.  When ever I create an instance of ChromiumWebBrowser it has a transparent background.  How do I turn this off?

```
private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
                    ChromiumWebBrowser cwb = new ChromiumWebBrowser();
                    cwb.IsBrowserInitializedChanged += Cwb_IsBrowserInitializedChanged;
}


 private void Cwb_IsBrowserInitializedChanged(object sender, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
{
            ChromiumWebBrowser cwb = (ChromiumWebBrowser)sender;
            cwb.Load("url");
}
```

Comment: Show a code snippet of the control.

Comment: Did you specify a background color?  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.controls.control.background?view=netframework-4.8

Comment: @ΩmegaMan  I have added the code snippet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`ChromiumWebBrowser`'s default control template doesn't have any way to set a background color. In my apps, I just put a `Border` behind the control. Simple.

Otherise, you can override the [default style/control template](https://github.com/cefsharp/CefSharp/blob/master/CefSharp.Wpf/Themes/Generic.xaml) and implement your own.

Comment: I ended up just appending the following code to the bottom of the html page:

```
 <style id="compiled-css" type="text/css">
      body { 
 background-color: white;
}
```